# Inconsistent object length in Javascript (HTMLCollection)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate over children of an HTMLCollection but am getting inconsistent results. To be more specific I am getting 3 items when there are 6 in total.

Here is how I get the elements:

```js
var entries = doc.getElementById("entries").children
```

This is what logged printed in the console:

[image]

This is perfect, just what I need. Now when I click on the toggle, here is what I get:

[image]

Furthermore, if I iterate of the elements:

```js
for (let entry of entries) { 
  console.log(entry);
}
```

Here is what I get (only three items):

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening. Would love any ideas from the community. Thanks in advance.

P.S.
Just to be sure I did `console.log(entries.length)` and the output is `6`.

P.P.S
I have also tried a different for in loop. The output was the same.

[Edit]
Here is the code examples for this issue.

In javascript, I fetch the "next" page, parse the HTML with DOMParser, grab only the `children` of the DOM Element with id "entries". Then I iterate over those children of which there are 6.

```js
loadMore(url, toAddLocation, pageLinks) {
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/html")
            
            console.log(doc.getElementById("entries"))
            console.log(typeof doc.getElementById("entries"))
            var entries = doc.getElementById("entries").children

            console.log(entries, entries.length)
            for (let entry of entries) { 
                console.log(entry);
                toAddLocation.appendChild(entry)
            }
            var pagination = doc.getElementById("pagination").innerHTML
            pageLinks.innerHTML = pagination;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
```

Here is the HTML I am trying to parse. I've left the block of interest:

```html
<div data-target="infinite-scroll.entries" id="entries">
  <article>Item 1</article>
  <article>Item 2</article>
  <article>Item 3</article>
  <article>Item 4</article>
  <article>Item 5</article>
  <article>Item 6</article>
</div>
```

Please let me know if there is more info you need.

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well please instead of images. thanks

Comment: This HTMLCollection is **live**, if the elements are removed after you got the object, then they won't be in that object anymore. You can *freeze* it in an Array by doing `frozen = [...entries]`. But please also include whatever could be interacting with these elements afterward so we don't only speculate.

Comment: Please include code that replicates the issue. Preferably as a [MCVE]

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have added the code examples.

Comment: Kaiido, Jon P, AlwaysHelping, I've updated the code. Could you take a look please?

Answer (score 2):

Freezing the HTMLCollection into an Array fixed the issue, just like Kaiido suggested.

So, I changed

```js
var entries = doc.getElementById("entries").children
```

to

```js
var entries = [...doc.getElementById("entries").children]
```